# How do I generate a UUID from a byte array in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a byte array generated by concatenating various columns and then hashing them. I would like to convert this `bytea` into a `uuid`.

But how do I generate a UUID from a byte array in Postgres?

---

Ideally, I would be able to replicate this .NET code:

```ml
open System
open System.Security.Cryptography

let a = Guid.Parse "45774962-e6f7-41f6-b940-72ef63fa1943"
let b = Guid.Parse "dfeb388b-ed66-4427-899d-3664f9f2b132"

let bytes =
  [|
    yield! a.ToByteArray()
    yield! b.ToByteArray()
  |]

let sha256 = SHA256.Create()

let hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes)

let deterministicID =
  hash
  |> Array.truncate 16
  |> Guid

printfn "%A" deterministicID

// cc36f34a-62ee-18b3-fa6b-efe3aab491b7
```

Comment: Looks like you need to go via hex string.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to leverage UUID v5.

**Text**

In Postgres:

```sql
SELECT uuid_generate_v5('46e65f20-b8dd-4c2e-a543-4a4df9a6a264', 'abc') AS id
-- 6952b59d-2dd0-501f-bd34-03dca112ba0b
```

In .NET:

```ml
let ns = Guid.Parse "46e65f20-b8dd-4c2e-a543-4a4df9a6a264"

let g = guidV5FromText ns "abc" 

printfn "%A" g
// 6952b59d-2dd0-501f-d034-03dca112ba0b
```

**UUID**

In Postgres:

```sql
WITH xs AS (
  SELECT '45774962-e6f7-41f6-b940-72ef63fa1943'::uuid AS x
)

SELECT uuid_generate_v5(
    '46e65f20-b8dd-4c2e-a543-4a4df9a6a264'::uuid,
    x::text
  ) AS id
FROM xs
-- 7f3625d2-757f-59cf-aaf3-e34e5b04adca
```

In .NET:

```ml
let ns = Guid.Parse "46e65f20-b8dd-4c2e-a543-4a4df9a6a264"

let x = Guid.Parse "45774962-e6f7-41f6-b940-72ef63fa1943"

let g = guidV5FromText ns (string x)

printfn "%A" g
// 7f3625d2-757f-59cf-d9f3-e34e5b04adca
```

**Multiple UUIDs**

```sql
WITH xs AS (
  SELECT 
    '45774962-e6f7-41f6-b940-72ef63fa1943'::uuid AS a,
    'dfeb388b-ed66-4427-899d-3664f9f2b132'::uuid AS b
)

SELECT uuid_generate_v5(
    '46e65f20-b8dd-4c2e-a543-4a4df9a6a264'::uuid,
    a::text || b::text
  ) AS id
FROM xs
-- d675a05a-c642-54a1-93fc-84d52b47235d
```

In .NET:

```ml
let ns = Guid.Parse "46e65f20-b8dd-4c2e-a543-4a4df9a6a264"

let a = Guid.Parse "45774962-e6f7-41f6-b940-72ef63fa1943"
let b = Guid.Parse "dfeb388b-ed66-4427-899d-3664f9f2b132"

let g = guidV5FromText ns (string a + string b)

printfn "%A" g
// d675a05a-c642-54a1-d4fc-84d52b47235d
```

---

.NET implementation:

```ml
let swapBytes (xs : byte array) (left : int) (right : int) =
  let temp = xs.[left]
  xs[left] <- xs[right]
  xs[right] <- temp

let swapByteOrder (xs : byte array) =
  swapBytes xs 0 3
  swapBytes xs 1 2
  swapBytes xs 4 5
  swapBytes xs 6 7

let guidV5 (namespaceID : Guid) (content : byte array) =
  use hasher = SHA1.Create()

  let namespaceBytes = namespaceID.ToByteArray()
  swapByteOrder namespaceBytes

  let bytes =
    Array.append
      namespaceBytes
      content

  let hash =
    hasher.ComputeHash(bytes)
    |> Array.truncate 16

  // Set high-nibble to 5 to indicate type 5
  hash[6] <- hash[6] &&& 0x0Fuy
  hash[6] <- hash[6] ||| 0x50uy

  // Set upper two bits to "10"
  hash[8] <- hash[6] &&& 0x3Fuy
  hash[8] <- hash[6] ||| 0x80uy

  swapByteOrder hash

  Guid hash

let guidV5FromText (namespaceID : Guid) (name : string) =
  guidV5 namespaceID (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes name)
```